# git fetch and checkout into various branches and run shell script on all the branches simultaneously using python multi-threading or milti-processing

Tags: python, git, multithreading, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am new to this.
I need to run a shell script on a few different branches of the same repo. I usually do this one by one, by doing a git fetch checkout head to one branch and running the script on that branch. And then move on to the next branch.
I am trying to write a python script to automate this. I am able to iterate(using a for loop) and run the shell script one by one(using subprocess). However the shell script takes too long to execute on each branch.
Is there a way to do this simultaneously?
How can I checkout into all the branches parallelly and run the shell script on all of them? Should I use multithreading or multiprocessing?
Thank you

Comment: I would think that your checkout command would require the *--work-tree* argument pointing to a different directory for each concurrent/parallel checkout that you do to avoid overlaying checked out files on top of one another. Otherwise, since `subprocess` is already creating a process, you really only need to be using multithreading to concurrently invoke calls to `subprocess`. But that's assuming that your "worker function" being invoked by multithreading isn't doing much more that just invoking `subprocess.run` (or maybe `subprocess.call`). You should post it with a solution attempt.

Comment: "*How can I checkout into all the branches parallelly and run the shell script on all of them?*" `git clone -b` or [`git worktree add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). "*Should I use multithreading or multiprocessing?*" Up to you. If it's a shell script you don't need Python at all, you can use [GNU `parallel`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.